# Change the text in a button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a FAQ list that works that way : there are several mini cards that contain a question (some text) and a button (let's say "see the answer"). When I click on the button, the answer to the question appears above the button. Then the button should not be a "see the answer" button, but a "close" one. I need a little help with that last part.

Here is what I have done :

```
<p>Question</p>
<div class="collapse" id="FAQ">
    <div class="well">
        Answer to the question
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="FAQ" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">See the answer</a>
```

Side question : since this is a list and I'm going to have several "See the answer/Close" buttons, I would say I'm not allowed to use an id to make it work, am I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically set the text on the button by `$(".btn").innerHTML = "new text to be displayed"`. Put this in your first `click(function() {...})` function.

And no, **never** use the same id for multiple elements. Use classes instead. You can have multiple classes on one element. So for example you may have `class="btn close"` and then use `toggleClass("close")` to add it when it's not there, remove it when it is.